# DynamicTreeUsing D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

1. We want data to be read from API apart from local json file. How is ajax call possible instead of `data.json` file from local directory.
2. When we  click last node the dynamic chart gauge will be generated not in page load in first node
3. How dropdown checkbox read data from json file.

Here we are using `d3.js`,`json`,`javascript`,`jquery`

Find out attached [js unit](https://jumpshare.com/v/Zdea8KRaxxtif58Nz9xt) and screen shot

[image: screen shot]